# HTML5 Server-sent events with Python cgi script on CGIHTTPServer

Tags: python, html, server-sent-events

I am testing HTML5 server sent events to see if I can use it in my project.  I tried to follow the tutorial on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp, but could not get it to work.

Here's my html (sse.html) and python cgi script (sse.py)：

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var source = new EventSource("/cgi-bin/sse.py");
   source.onmessage = function(event) {
       console.log(event.data);
   };
</script>
</head>
<body>
Testing SSE!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

sse.py as follows:

```
import sys
import datetime
import time

sys.stdout.write('Content-type: text/event-stream\r\n\r\n')

while True:
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   sys.stdout.write('data: %s\r\n\r\n' % now)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(5)
```

I put 'sse.html' into 'c:\code\sse', and 'sse.py' into 'c:\code\sse\cgi-bin'.  Then, I ran 'python -m CGIHTTPServer' to bring up the development web server.

When I connected to 'http://localhost:8000/sse.html', I didn't see the console logging the data received from the server.  Instead, I saw a message saying that "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "chrome-extension://hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl/bar.js"."

Does anyone know what would be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I modified 'sse.py' by trials and errors, and the code is working now.  The new 'sse.py' is as follows:

```
import sys
import datetime
import time

sys.stdout.write('Content-type: text/event-stream \r\n\r\n')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
sys.stdout.write('data: %s \r\n' % now)
sys.stdout.write('retry: 1000\r\n\r\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I am still trying to figure out how things work.

Comment: I'm not sure 'retry' field solved your issue. But make sure that the response is encoded in UTF-8 and accordingly content-type header should be 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8'.

Comment: 'retry' is for setting up the interval for client to visit the script again.  If I take out the statement for setup the 'retry' interval, and add one more '\r\n' to the statement above.  The code will still work, but the time interval will become 3 seconds.
What I don't understand is that based on what I read, it seems like we only need to set the content type once, and the client will always wait for message with 'data:' prefix.  But the modified code shows that it seems like we need to specify the content type for each message.

Comment: I don't know Python so can't give you a clear answer but something is clearly wrong. As the author of real-time web application framework, [Cettia](http://cettia.io), I've never used retry field in dealing with Server-Sent Events. Because you seem to print raw HTTP message unlike what you read (they are using framework not deal with HTTP message lines directly), I suspect you should follow [Chunked Transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Comment: Then, the right plain message of HTTP response following event-stream format from Server-Sent Events spec will look like [here](http://vibe-project.github.io/blog/anatomy-of-vibe-protocol/) See 'HTTP request/response for the client to receive data from the server' section. FYI, Vibe is a previous name of Cettia.

Comment: I think you need to look up nph scripts.